# My two Jquery scripts are interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

What should I do so I can utilize both functions?

The first is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();  
  });
});
```

The second is:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
  $root.animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

What is the proper syntax to utilize both scripts? Thank you!

Comment: In what way, precisely, are they interfering? What are they doing currently and what are you instead expecting of them? It may also help if you would be able to create a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.

Comment: do you have any `<a class="toggle-nav">`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `attr()` incorrectly. Try changing

```
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
```

To

```
scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
```

If still having issues, check browser dev tools console for any errors